# Simulating the robot using moveit with ROS

Tags: ros, gazebo

I'm an absolute beginner in this field so I request you to help me although the question seems very silly.

I want to send the robot (in simulation) pose goal from ROS node. I want to use to moveit framework. Previously I have used V-REP simulator and controlled a robot in V-REP using ROS node.

I want to do same by using moveit framework and gazebo simulator. I have already created the panda_moveit_config package but I don't know what to do next. My main questions are:

1. Where can I keep my source file of ROS node(containing the code to control the robot)?
2. How can I run the node and send commands to robot model in Gazebo?

I'm looking forward to any tutorials or advice which will help me from environment setup till running the code. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Vishal, welcome on Robotics, it seems to me that your question can be answered by following basic tutorials from the ros.org website

Comment: Precisely can you suggest any tutorial?? I have done motion planning in moveit and now i want to see the robot arm moving as per the planned path in gazebo simulator

Comment: as you don't know where to put  your source code I would suggest you with the very first beginner tutorial on ros.org so that you get familiar with the concepts used by ROS and the usual worklfow. Then every "big" package has some tutorials on it's page, it's true for movit, gazebo ...

Answer (score 1):

After generating the moveit_config package you have to do a lot of work to get it working in simulation.

1)make sure your robot urdf has inertia parameters, if not guess them reasonably.

2)add transmissions to all joints in the urdf and load the gazebo_ros_control plugin (check out gazebo grasp_fix plugin incase you have trouble grasping)

3)add create a controller.yaml file specifying which controller you want to use for each joints

4)create a launch file for spawning model, spawning ros_controllers in gazebo

5)edit moveit_controllers.launch to link moveit to the controllers you have spawned.

I suggest you go through these links: [1](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_control#Tutorial:ROSControl) ,[2](https://github.com/JoshMarino/gazebo_and_ros_control#Torque%20Control) , [3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6bBxfD_bYs), [4](http://www.theconstructsim.com/control-gazebo-simulated-robot-moveit-video-answer/)

Comment: I think you'll get more help in ROS Answers

Comment: Thank you @Allwin, I found [New setup assistance tool] (http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/setup_assistant/setup_assistant_tutorial.html)  from moveit which does most of the work related to URDF file. I'll check the links you suggested and post my findings here.